# Spring Boot JPA Load Many to many

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, spring-data, hibernate-mapping

I have this two tables:

```
Student 
- id
- name
- List<Course>

Course
- id
- title
- List<Student>
```

I have a `StudentRepository` and a `CourseRepository` (JpaRepository).

When I load the Students with the following code:

```
    fun getAll(): List<Student> {
        return studentRepository.findAll()
    }
```

I get an infinite list.

But I expect this JSON output:

```
[
 {
  "id":1,
  "name":"Ben"
  "course": [
   {
   "id":1,
   "title":"Math"
   },
   {
    "id":2,
    "title":"English"
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

How do I get this result?

**//EDIT:**
I get an infinite List
[image]

Comment: Can you please add exact code from those objects ?

Comment: There are 2 problems here: 1) how to convert response to JSON 2) is the default Fetch strategy a viable option

Answer (score 2):

If you're using jackson, you can generate json of parent only in child by using `@JsonBackReference` (over child) and `@JsonManagedReference` (over parent) annotations.

If you want to suppress printing the relation, you can use `@JsonIgnore` or `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotations over the field not to be serialized.

Here is an example for `Course` class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "students" })
class Course(...)
```

You can find more example [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization).

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `List<Student>` in your Course class unless you need to navigate the relationship in both direction: Student->Course and Course ->Student.

If thats the case then you need to pay attention how you navigate the graph: in a loop where you use/print all Student attributes (ie incl courses) Hibernate will fetch the data, firing the extra query when needed (ie course.student).

A situation where this happens is when each Class has a toString() printing all attributes of the class: in a loop of Students log each iteration to trigger that infinite chain of call.

Comment: Why not? It is a many to many relationship. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Entity
class Student {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "course_like", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"))
    List<Course> likedCourses;

    // additional properties
    // standard constructors, getters, and setters
}

@Entity
class Course {

    @Id
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "likedCourses")
    Set<Student> likes;

    // additional properties
    // standard constructors, getters, and setters
}
```

The owner side is where we configure the relationship, which for this example we'll pick the Student class.

Note, that using ***@JoinTable***, or even ***@JoinColumn*** isn't required: JPA will generate the table and column names for us. However, the strategy JPA uses won't always match the naming conventions we use. Hence the possibility to configure table and column names.

On the target side, we only have to provide the name of the field, which maps the relationship. Therefore, we set the mappedBy attribute of the ***@ManyToMany*** annotation in the Course class: